# Is "Whichever" correctly used here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

In the sentence bellow, is whichever correctly used?

> *Whichever* way you look at it, it'll still sound outrageous

What I want to say in this sentence is:

> It doesn't matter which way you look at it, it'll still sound outrageous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps "Whatever", though your sentence is also correct.

"Whichever" suggests that there are a only a few options to how you can interpret it, so if you had described the ways that you could look at it in the previous paragraph you would use "whichever".  It is the same distinction between "which" and "what".